Separate vs joint continuous bilinear maps: examples?
A good application of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem is the fact that separate continuity of bilinear maps implies joint continuity, on Banach spaces. But what would be a good application of this fact?
I can think only of the definition of Banach algebras, this proves that allowing separately continuous multiplication would not widen their class. But anything else, suitable for the same course where the B-S theorem is introduced?
Thank you in advance!

For example if $T_n:\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$  is sequence of bounded operators such that the sequence of numbers $|T_n|$ is unbounded, then the sequence  $T_nx$ is unbounded for some $x\in \mathcal{H}.$

Yes, sure, there are good applications of the theorem itself. But of this bilinear operator fact? So that it does not appear just as an exercise to practise the theorem.

See this

This will work perfectly, thank you!
